# C++ How to copy this array type to a Vector

Tags: c++

C++ How to copy this array type to a Vector

I got this array which is of class VehicleTwoD

I declare it this way at main function

```
VehicleTwod *vechicletwod[100];

//after some computation
//vechicletwod got until [5];
```

//now i need do sorting, but i prefer do it in vector. how do i copy the content of vehicletwod into an vector of the same type

I did something like

```
vector<VehicleTwoD> sortVector;
sortVector = shapetwod;
```

but i get some error for no match operator= in sortVector = vehicletwod;

Thanks for all help !

Comment: Why use arrays when you can do it all on a `vector`?

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to why the first has pointers.

Comment: Also is it a typo or did you mean to have 2 types, `VehicleTwod` and `VehicleTwoD`

Comment: If this is the same exercise that you have posted about before, then you need a vector of *pointers*, `vector<VehicleTwoD*> sortVector;`. And the way you copy is very simple `sortVector.assign(vechicletwod, vechicletwod + 100);`. This assumes you have 100 pointers in your array, if not substitute the real number for 100.

Comment: @chris Because previously this was an exercise in polymorphism.

Comment: @john, Ok, that makes sense, although now it becomes why the second doesn't use pointers, which is kind of the point.

Comment: @chris I suspect that it's just a mistake on the OP's part. Which makes most of the answers unhelpful.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, your going to have loop through the array:

```
for (const auto& p : vechicletwod)
{
    sortVector.emplace_back(*p);
}
```

The better option would be to just use `vector<VehicleTwoD> sortVector;` from the start.

Comment: Or use something like this: `std::transform(std::begin(vehicletwod), std::end(vehicletwod), std::back_inserter(sortVector), [](VehicleTwoD *arg){return *arg;});`

Comment: @chris: Yes, I considered using something in `<algorithm>`, but any solution would be more verbose.

Comment: Agreed. It would be more manageable with a `std::dereferences`, at the very least.

Comment: @user1595932: What compiler are you using? You may need to upgrade to use this answer.

Comment: If you can't upgrade, use a normal for loop and `push_back`: `for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { sortVector.push_back(*vechicletwod[i]) }`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just make a vector of type *VehicleTwod, i.e vector<*VehicleTwod> sortVector. You could then iterate through your array and push_back each element.

Perhaps something like this:

```
typedef vector<*VehicleTwod> vecPtrVehicle2d;
typedef vecPtrVehicle2d::iterator vecPtrVehicle2dIter;

vecPtrVehicleWod sortVector;
int i, n = 100;

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  sortVector.push_back(vechicletwod[i]);
```

You don't need the vector iterator just here, I tend to do it by habit.

Answer (score 0):

Your types are inconsistent.

```
VehicleTwod *vechicletwod[100];
```

declares an array of VehicleTwod *pointers*, while your vector is declared to store actual VehicleTwod objects, not their memory addresses. Try initializing vechicletwod without the '*':

```
 VehicleTwod vechicletwod[100]; //array of actual objects
```

or changing the vector to contain pointers:

```
vector<VehicleTwoD*> sortVector;
```

Once the types work out, you can use the '=' operator exactly as you tried in the first place.

```
   sortVector = vehicletwod; //overloaded = operator in class vector
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question on how he could **transfer** the contents of the array to a vector.

Comment: If the types are the same, the overloaded '=' operator should work exactly as he tried in the first place. The error arises because the operator is overloaded for the type the vector holds, so there is no matching operator for the given type.